# Stop grails is not a valid candidate

Tags: java, grails

I was once coding and wanted to call grails to do some spring security configuration only to see this grails cannot be found.
After i run....sdk install grails, 
it responded like this "stop! grails is not a valid candidate"

Answer (score 0):

For such an issue you need to know you candidate has been cached, its funny but, you can copy or enter this in your terminal
...$ curl -s https://api.sdkman.io/candidates > ~/.sdkman/var/candidates...

if the issue persist kindly remove the s infront of the https and use this 
...$ curl -s http://api.sdkman.io/candidates > ~/.sdkman/var/candidates...

if the issue still persist you can let me know and we will see how to help

For more explaination follow the link https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/425 he did a great work helping.